# Numpy where returning error where it shouldn't

Tags: python, numpy, debugging, neural-network, numpy-ndarray

I am working with Neural Network from scratch and when I try to implement the stable sigmoid function, numpy where seems to behave strangely. Both functions here return ***RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp***:

```
#Original Function

def sigmoid(x):
    return np.where(x >= 0, 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x)))

#Dummy function that is also misbehaving

def sigmoid(x):
    return np.where(x>=0, 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), 0)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: `where` does not prevent the evaluation over whole array.  This is python

Comment: How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It is possible suppress warnings.  Or `ufunc` like `np.exp` have their own `where` mechanism.  You can also `clip` the `x` values before pass to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a runtime warning and not an error. Your code works perfectly fine. The warning is because you are trying to calculate `exp(-(-1000))` which overflows float capacity (essentially returns `inf`). Since you have it in the denominator, I would not worry about it, bacuase it returns `1/inf = 0`.